# Код в JS файле в нечитабельном виде

Tags: javascript

Есть файл JS для сайта, но его содержимое то ли зашифровано, то ли ещё как то по хитрому скрыто, читабельная часть есть только в самом начале файла. Можно ли как то привезти этот файл к нормальному виду, чтобы можно было править его код?
 Сам файл довольно большой и почти весь состоит из вот этого вот бреда, только в конце есть слова разделенные вертикальной чертой (|).
Вот кусок кода этого файла с читабельной первой частью.

```
eval(function(p,a,c,k,e,d){e=function(c){return(c<a?'':e(parseInt(c/a)))+((c=c%a)>35?String.fromCharCode(c+29):c.toString(36))};if(!''.replace(/^/,String)){while(c--)d[e(c)]=k[c]||e(c);k=[function(e){return d[e]}];e=function(){return'\\w+'};c=1};while(c--)if(k[c])p=p.replace(new RegExp('\\b'+e(c)+'\\b','g'),k[c]);return p}('1a 43=43?43:{};(1c(ao,an){1a al=ao.1P,bH=ao.3l,by=ao.4i;1a aj=(1c(){1a bN=1c(bY,bX){1b 3b bN.fn.3A(bY,bX,E)},bR=ao.3f,H=ao.$,E,bV=/^(?:[^#<]*(<[\\w\\W]+>)[^>]*$|#([\\w\\-]*)$)/,bI=/\\S/,J=/^\\s+/,F=/\\s+$/,I=/\\d/,B=/^<(\\w+)\\s*\\/?>(?:<\\/\\1>)?$/,bJ=/^[\\],:{}\\s]*$/,bT=/\\\\(?:["\\\\\\/Ie]|u[0-9a-fA-F]{4})/g,bL=/"[^"\\\\\\n\\r]*"|1g|1i|1m|-?\\d+(?:\\.\\d*)?(?:[eE][+\\-]?\\d+)?/g,K=/(?:^|:|,)(?:\\s*\\[)+/g,z=/(8T)[ \\/]([\\w.]+)/,bO=/(Ic)(?:.*2x)?[ \\/]([\\w.]+)/,bM=/(2q) ([\\w.]+)/,bP=/(oc)(?:.*? rv:([\\w.]+))?/,C=/-([a-z]|[0-9])/ig,bW=/^-ms-/,bQ=1c(bY,bX){1b(bX+"").1u()},bU=bH.3T,bS,D,e,M=fZ.4v.io,G=fZ.4v.y2,A=7s.4v.2Z,L=7s.4v.6u,bK=iH.4v.7K,w=7s.4v.1I,y={};bN.fn=bN.4v={cX:bN,3A:1c(bY,bX,b3){1a b2,b0,bZ,b1;if(!bY){1b 1h}if(bY.1U){1h.1d=1h[0]=bY;1h.1j=1;1b 1h}if(bY==="3c"&&!bX&&al.3c){1h.1d=al;1h[0]=al.3c;1h.4T=bY;1h.1j=1;1b 1h}if(1x bY==="2z"){if(bY.rH(0)==="<"&&bY.rH(bY.1j-1)===">"&&bY.1j>=3){b2=[1m,bY,1m]}1f{b2=bV.4a(bY)}if(b2&&(b2[1]||!bX)){if(b2[1]){bX=bX gk
```

Comment: он просто минифицирован

Comment: @MykolaVeriga Похоже, что он еще и зашифрован

Comment: @MykolaVeriga А есть способ его "максифицировать"? (простите за мой английский)))

Comment: @Anton Shchyrov Думаю что даже если и зашифрован, то способ расшифровки должен быть в самом файле, потому как других зашифрованных файлов нет, да и других JS файлов тоже, только html и css, но в них я ни чего интересного не увидел.

Comment: скиньте файл, возможно предложу что то позже

Comment: @Ден Еще может ключ лежать в html или подтягиваться аяксом. Это не авито, случайно?

Comment: @MykolaVeriga вот сам файл - https://drive.google.com/file/d/1cXXKR7Md5qrJpMXRfnmGkN5QJQD8gFvH/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @Anton Shchyrov Нет, не авито))) Всего лишь фото-галерея, просто прога которая эту галерею создает, ну скажем так, на таблетках)))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В коде есть метод [eval](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval)

Метод eval() выполняет JavaScript код, представленный строкой.

например

```
eval('alert'.concat('(120)'));
```

Мы просто берем все что внутри eval. Как уже понятно оно генерирует строку. Как оно это делает нам неважно. И вставляем все это в обычный

```
 console.log('alert'.concat('(120)'));
```

И в консоли видим нужную строку, а то есть код который и  нужен.

ссылка на результат, это чисто ради эксперимента

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1QVksQquHQ6XDZCfcWoybhQcLsyv0Xq6T

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, нашел я нужные строчки (хоть и тоже с грехом пополам и трех-этажным матом))). Если бы знал возможно ли тут как то + поставить, то поставил бы обязательно!